# Unable to Install ipa for my testing app

Tags: xcode, ipa

I engaged a freelancer on my ios app developing and he sent over a link via diawi to download the ipa. However nothing seems to work..All my Apple devices stopped at installing stage. Funny thing is it works on my freelancer apple devices (He showed me video of him installing via diawi, it was installed and works)

I looked up all the possible answers from this site and tried all the suggested solutions but nothing works.

I have checked

1. All UDID are registered (not the FFFF...) I got my UDID from itunes.
2. Software updated iOS 8
3. I installed via diawi...failed at installing (stuck for hours)
4. I installed via itunes....failed at installing
5. Testflight as well failed....unable to complete installing.

I tried on 2 different iphone 6, iphone 5s, ipad mini, ipad 3. I am in China but it shouldn't be a problem...or is it? A friend in Malaysia tried and able to install just not mine. Is there something I am doing wrong? Please help!

fyi - my developer using xcode 6.3, I don't have mac

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and it turned out my provisioning profile and certificates had expired.